# PhoneGap - sending/fetching constantly fleet cars' positions - best approach?

Tags: cordova, gps, location

I have to develope a taxi app.

The plan/needs would be this: 
    Driver's device:
       *- send position to server when it changes (at a frequency depending on driver's status - busy, available, etc.. - I am more interested in accuracy position of an available driver rather than a busy one, but this is not very important..)* 

   Requester's device: 
       *- get as updated as posible the position of all drivers on a map (a google one, most probably)*

Things I am worried about are: ***performance***, ***net traffic*** and ***battery economy***.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to thing this through, are you creating this app for small number of drivers or a large number.

- This is way is it important to choose a proper js framework. Phonegap will be a wrapper of course. Top combination for a real time java script client / server communication architecture is a Node.js and SOCKET.IO framework. Unfortunately they are useful only in a clean hybrid app (app built without some js mobile app framework like jQuery Mobile, jQMoby ....).

If you are going to use a js mobile app framework you will need to use it in combination with backbone js framework. Not nearly good as node.js and socket IO but still a good combination. Node.js and socket IO don't play well with other js mobile app frameworks.

- Use phonegap geolocation API to acquire a car lat and lng position. Unlike sport GPS applications you don't need to refresh every second. Cars are going through the predefined routs so 30 sec refresh time will be enough.
- Don't tie 30 sec interval to the real time (11:00:00, 11:00:30, 11:01:00 ...) because every single device will try to send a location refresh at the same time and that will kill a server infrastructure. It is better to time it every 30 sec after app is initialized.
- Driver's device app could be a small app. It will work as a background process. Because data will be sent every 30 sec net traffic and batter life want be a real problem.
- Requester device will get a bulk data (every possible car in some radius around requester device) every predefined time. Before server can send bulk data requester must send its location. It will be used to get nearest cars.
- Google Maps mobile API v3 will be used as a map at a requester device. Because this is a mobile device and mobile frameworks are not know for they excellent performances, don't use it do display more then 100 cars (few hundred at best in case of desktop web app).
- My final advice is, if possible create a native mobile app, because hybrid mobile apps are not that good at handling real time data. At lease not a large amount of data. Stick with a longer transition interval, it will save your battery. And don't think of using a XML as a client/server data. It has a large data overhead.

[Node.js](http://nodejs.org/)

[Socket.IO](http://socket.io/)

Comment: Unfortunately, I need the capabilities of a taxi app. There are no predefined routs. I might need to see all the cars, whatever their location is relative to the requester's. So we can talk literally about the needs of a taxi app. I might havo to change the question too. So, from what you suggest, I see that it would be recomanded a pure native mobile app for this, though it would be great to develope it using PhoneGap and jQueryMobile - I can save a lot of time with those.

Comment: What I told you can also be used in a taxi app, like a common car taxi can go only through the predefined streets. So 30 sec is still a good refresh rate. jQuery Mobile and Phonegap is still a good platform but it will not be enough for a large number of cars.

Comment: I see. What about notifications? Initialy I thought about doing some Ajax from time to time and check if any request has been made for a particular driver. Then I read about Google Cloud Messaging. Have you worked with this and PhoneGap together? Can you give me some advices/resources regarding it? Thank you!

Comment: Sorry, I have never used Google Cloud Messaging service. Mainly because to make a distance from 3rd party services. Node.js and Socket.IO is my winning combination but it wont work well with jQuery Mobile (tried that and failed miserably).

Comment: I understand. I can make some views/layouts without jQueryMobile while I'm using html/css for that in PhoneGap. Now I have to see how can I work with those two (Node.js and Socket.IO). Is there any good/efficient starting point?

Comment: It is funny but for me the best entry point were youtube presentations like this one: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EdMCCxtepHk and this one http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dcsVyRVvpAw .

Comment: No problem m8 :) happy to help